# How do I reach request body in Strapi middleware?

Tags: node.js, post, koa, strapi

I have managed to make middleware work in Strapi. But, I can't see the body in the request.

Inside /middlewares/getEmail/index.js, I Have

```
module.exports = (strapi) => {
  return {
    initialize: function (cb) {
      strapi.app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
        if (ctx.method === "POST" && ctx.url === "/email-leads") {
          console.log(ctx);
        }
        await next();
      });
    },
  };
};
```

and ctx request logs:

```
  request: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/email-leads',
    header: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      accept: 'application/json',
      'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.8',
      'postman-token': 'xxx',
      host: 'localhost:1337',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'content-length': '33'
    }
  },
```

This is the only middleware I have written on this application. In the /config/middleware.js, I have

```
module.exports = {
  load: {
    before: ["getEmail", "responseTime", "logger", "cors", "responses", "gzip"],
    order: ["parser"],
    after: ["router"],
  },
  settings: {
    getEmail: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
};
```

I read about this **koa-body/unparsed.js** to read the body but there's literally no body in the ctx.request. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have reached a solution. Posting here in case anyone else needs it.

In `config/middleware.js`, I have changed the load, taking the custom middleware to `after` array.

```
  load: {
    before: ["responseTime", "logger", "cors", "responses", "gzip"],
    after: ["parser", "router", "getEmail"],
  },
```

I still can't see the `ctx.request.body` if I log `ctx` or `ctx.request`. But, if I use `ctx.request.body` directly, I can reach it in case the load is written as above (or custom middleware after `parser`).

Answer (score 2):

if you `console.log(ctx.request.body);` before `await next();` line it will prints `undefined` because body is not loaded yet. so you have 2 option for fetching body.

1. Use `console.log(ctx.request.body);` after `await next();` line
2. Load body from raw node request like below example

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnAcq.png)